# ExpandableListView change the expanding mode to horizontally

Tags: android, layout, expandablelistview

I am trying to change the way in which ExpandableListView expands.
The default is vertically, but i want it to expand horizontally!

Something like this (http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/multi-pane-layouts.html), but this uses multi-pane.

What I want to do is that when the parent is clicked, the child will expand in line with the parent, not under it.

Default is:

```
Parent1
  Child1
Parent2
  Child2
```

What I want is:

```
Parent1     Child1
Parent2     Child2
```

Main.xml:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.list"
        android:background="#141214"
        >
     <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"
            android:fadingEdge="vertical"

           />
```

Parent_View.xml:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <CheckedTextView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

            android:id="@+id/textViewGroupName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"

            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="30dp"

            android:textSelectHandleLeft="@string/hello_world"
            android:background="#009999"
            android:textStyle="bold"
             />
```

Child View.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="#99D6D6"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewChild"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#1919A3"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So is there any way to modify the ExpandableListView properties so that the children will be shown in line with parents?

Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried to achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: WEll, it seems just a normal ListView. Using **Fragments**

Comment: Added the .xml files. Thank you again